# oAuth: client credentials flow and execution user

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

[image: screenshot from Salesforce's Postman responses when trying to get a token]

Hey folks.

I am trying to obtain a token using the `client_credentials` flow and have had little success.

What I did so far:

- Create the Connected App
- Enabled IP Relaxation
- Managed successfully to get a token using the `password` flow (hitting the same **token** endpoint)
- **edit #1** After the first comment, I also added the **Run As** as below.
  [image: manage policies screen]

Again, my problem is stated in the error message Salesforce returns to my POST:

```json
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "no client credentials user enabled"
}
```

Any clues on what would be the solution? I am inclined to say I need some sort of **Execution User** activated ~~but so far I am clueless about where to add that (if that is a thing)~~**edit #1**. A Google search did not return anything useful.

Comment: It's a User account that your token request will "run as": https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_client_credentials_setup.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to reflect that new knowledge.

Comment: BTW, adding it to the *Run As* shown in the screenshot did not make a difference yet. However, trying to add to the "Client Credentials Flow" causes the UI in the screenshot to complain (and not allow the add) with the error message that the user should have **API Only** Permissions.

Comment: Does that imply that I need to create a brand new user (regular user) and somewhere reduce its permissions to API-only access?

Comment: Any user with the appropriate license will work, separate user (aka _service account_) is recommended. API Only permission assigned to the user is required. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects covers the basics of data security and permissioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked in my personal org for the same implementation and faced the same issue. As my user is not API only user I faces it. I guess this is same in your scenario as well.

The users with " API Only " will not be able to log in to salesforce through UI.

> API Only - Specifies that the user can only log in through the API. This prevents the user from being used for any purpose other than integration scenarios.

Please find the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386144&type=1) for more details on this permission

Answer (score 0):

Key is also to enable it in the settings under OAuth and OpenlD Connect Settings -> Allow Authorization Code and Credentials Flows

Comment: No, enabling a headless flow and of a different grant type to boot has nothing to do with `client_credentials`

Comment: Afterwards it worked for us and before not

Comment: Uncorrelated change.